# Python script to check whether url exists fails with HTTPConnectionPool error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have written the following python script to check whether a possible permutation of prefixes and suffixes exist as a website url:

```
import requests

prefix = ['test', 'trial','demo','check']
suffix = ['site','web','page']

results = []
domains = [] 
site_available = []
site_occupied = []

for elem in prefix:
    for i in suffix:
        results.append(elem+i)

for i in results:
    domains.append('http://www.{}.com'.format(i))


for site in domains:
    request = requests.get(site)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        site_occupied.append(site)
    else:
        site_available.append(site)
```

Unfortunately I keep seeing the following error:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.testpage.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x11326ccd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))
```

How can I resolve this error?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a `try-except` block to handle `ConnectionError`. I would add it in the loop:

```
for site in domains:
    try:
        request = requests.get(site)
    except requests.ConnectionError as ex:
        <exception handling code here>
        continue # <--- move to next loop iteration without trying to process a failed request
```

This may not be the most robust way of doing exception handling, but it should work for what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but it still gets stuck at the spot of the error

Comment: okay well it doesn't get stuck but took a while to check the url, so I guess I ll tinker around with a timeout and it will do it the trick, thanks!

Comment: Sure. `requests.request()` takes a `timeout=<float>` keyword argument that is applied to the underlying socket connection. If it's not specified, I believe it will block indefinitely (probably not what you want).

Comment: oops now it says ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.agri24.de', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=2)

Comment: You could handle that too by changing the `except ...` line to `except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.ReadTimeout) as ex:`